# ListView issue when displaying strings

Tags: android, listview

can any one help me to display set of results in my app in a list view. i got the following

```
codeList<Result> results = response.results;

        for (Result result : results) {
            //Toast.makeText(this, result.fromUser, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(this, result.text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //String[] ch=getResources().getString(result.text);//result.text;
            //adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.mainlist,result.text);
            //SimpleArrayAdapter adapter = new SimpleArrayAdapter(this, result.text);

            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

i want to show result.text in a listview for each value. i tried everything commented in the code, but not getting. please help me.

Comment: Go through the example given here: http://goo.gl/uzXrs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) extend ArrayAdapter with your custom class:

```
class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Result>
```

2) create xml for layout of each row, eg. `row.xml` and set it in constructor of your adapter:

```
    MyAdapter(Activity context, int resourceId, ArrayList<Result>
    mResults) {             
      super(context, R.layout.row, mResults);
 }
```

3) in `getView` method of your adapter fill apropriate field with your result.text
4) set list adapter to your custom adapter

```
   MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, 0, mResults);
  setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

with this short snippet of code it is hard to know what the problem might be,

possibly this will help
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html

after `setListAdapter(adapter);` try adding `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` or alternatively try `adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true)` just after initializing the adapter this might solve your issue if it is what i think it is. else post more of your code

Answer (score 1):

You can use    `**ExpandableListView**`

[image]

**Refer :** http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList3.html