# List array in a list view

Tags: android, listview, linked-list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ListView issue when displaying strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992639/listview-issue-when-displaying-strings)

I have the following code

```
List<Result> results = response.results;
```

i need the the values in "results" to be displayed in a listview. what should i write within `for (Result result : results){}`

Answer (score 1):

You've asked a general question so the best I can do is give you a general answer. You don't use `for(Results result: results){}` You need to use an [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html). For a tutorial on how to do so, please see [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html).

Comment: i tried array adapter, but not working.for (Result result : results) {adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.JsonParsingActivity,R.layout.mainlist,result.text);
         //SimpleArrayAdapter adapter = new SimpleArrayAdapter(this, result.text);} i tried this way, but not working.

Comment: Like I said in my post, don't use the for loop. Follow the example in documentation I gave you a link to.